# how HUD speedcam application was made?

Tags: iphone

Iphone HUD+ application that "projects" screen to whindshiled is interesting with its ability to flip the screen in mirror. 
Any idea how this is made?

Answer (score 1):

Every UIView has a `transform` property that can be set to any affine transform. You could use a transform that scales x by -1 (plus a screen wide translation) on the topmost view (the window).

If you want to know how the developers of the app in question did it, why not ask them directly?

Comment: This never occurred to me. Will ask him